# How to pass unknown uri's in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

we use for a spring web app angularJS and Jade. The files are located in the static-resource folder. When the user wants to access a page, Jade renders the file and returns the html-page. On loading the page needs other resources like css and js-files. I have the problem, that Spring trys to map these resource-requests and of course cannot find any mapping for it.

So I have tried to install a filter which should pass these requests directly to the resource folder without any request mapping or processing or something else.

```js
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
   ServletException {
  String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
  System.out.println("Filtering: " + uri);
  
      try{
       request.getRequestDispatcher(uri).forward(request, response);
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

It seems, that the filter calls recursively so the app runs into a stack overflow (at least I can see many exceptions in an endless loop always starting in doFilter()).

So how can I pass requests with an unknown mapping directly to the resource folder?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: Simply add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to your configuration, requests that cannot be handled by the `DispatcherServlet` will be processed by the default servlet handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a filter, you can configure a mapping for your static files inside your Spring MVC servlet XML configuration, in which case your requsts for CSS and JS would work out fine. The typical is to place the static files under a single folder, and make a mapping to that folder e.g.

1) the folder structure

```
| - resources
|  | - css
|  |   ` your CSS files...
|  | - js
|      ` your JS files...
| - WEB-INF
```

2) mapping requests the to the location of the static resources

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

or

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources");
    }
```

if you're using java configuration

3) the access to static resources from the JSPs, as

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/[your file].css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```